Why is my setTimeout function in JavaScript not executing multiple download rounds correctly?
I am trying to download multiple files sequentially in a JSP page using setTimeout and top.location.href, but the download process doesn't behave as expected. Instead of executing each download in separate rounds (with a 2-second delay), it seems like it only processes the first file and skips the others.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*, java.text.*, java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="sapphire.accessor.QueryProcessor, sapphire.util.DataSet, sapphire.util.StringUtil, sapphire.util.ActionBlock, sapphire.accessor.ActionProcessor, sapphire.util.DBAccess, sapphire.accessor.ActionException"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/sapphire.tld" prefix="sapphire" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/c.tld" prefix="c" %>
<sapphire:controlledpage allowanonymous="true"/>
<sapphire:page layout="${layout.objectname}">
<sapphire:pagecontent name="content">

<%!
    public void writeLog(String logstr) {
        String pathFile = "D:\\GenControlChartLog.txt";
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathFile, true)));
            out.println(new java.util.Date() + " - " + logstr);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
%>

<%
    writeLog("Start processing control charts");
    String data = requestinfo.getProperty("data");
    String sdate = requestinfo.getProperty("sdate");
    String edate = requestinfo.getProperty("edate");
    String scno = requestinfo.getProperty("scno");
    String[] _data = data.split("%3B");
    String filenameall = "";
    for(int i = 0;i<_data.length;i++) {
        String[] __data = _data[i].split(";");
        String filename = "ControlChart-"+__data[0]+"-"+i+"-" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss").format(new java.util.Date()) +".xlsx";
        String success = "";
        writeLog("filename = "+ filename);
        HashMap hm = new HashMap();
        hm.put("filename", filename);
        hm.put("keyid1", _data[i]);
        hm.put("sdate", sdate);
        hm.put("edate", edate);
        hm.put("scno", scno);
        ActionProcessor ap = new ActionProcessor(application.getInitParameter("nameserverlist"), pageinfo.getConnectionId());
        try {
            ap.processAction("ControlChartXLXS", "1", hm);
            success = "SUCCESS";    
            writeLog("ControlChartXLXS SUCCESS ");
        } catch (ActionException ae) {
            success = "FAILURE";
            writeLog("error1 :"+ae.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            success = "FAILURE";
            writeLog("error2 :"+e.getMessage());
        }
        if(i>0) {
            filenameall +="%3B";
        }
        filenameall +=filename;
    }
%>

<script>
    function downloadFile_V2(file, i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            top.sapphire.alert( 'into setTimeout Download round ' + i, true );
            console.log('into setTimeout Download round ' + i);
            top.location.href = "WEB-CUSTOM/Download/DownloadFile_00.jsp?filepath=WEB-CUSTOM/ControlChart/Output/" + file;
        }, i * 2000); 
    }

    var _filename = "<%=filenameall%>";
    console.log('filearrOG = ' + _filename);
    if (_filename != "") {
        var filearr = _filename.split("%3B");
        console.log('filearr after split = ' + filearr);
        top.sapphire.alert('filearr length = ' + filearr.length, true);
        for (let i = 0; i < filearr.length; i++) {
            top.sapphire.alert('filearr = ' + filearr[i], true);
            console.log('filearr = ' + filearr[i]);
            downloadFile_V2(filearr[i], i);
        }
    } else {
        top.sapphire.alert('Not Found Document Template!', true);
    }
</script>

</sapphire:pagecontent>
</sapphire:page>

Problem:
The downloadFile_V2 function is supposed to trigger downloads sequentially, with a 2-second delay between each round. However, only the first download occurs, and the others are skipped or not triggered.
I expect the logs to show
into setTimeout Download round 0
into setTimeout Download round 1
into setTimeout Download round 2
But instead, it only logs the first round (into setTimeout Download round 0).
What I've tried:
Used setTimeout with a delay of i * 2000 for each download.
Checked the length of the filearr array, and it seems correct.
Checked for any JavaScript errors, but none are shown.
Any suggestions on why this might be happening or how I can fix this?

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but won't the very first location change reload the page; reset the script; and clear all timeouts?

Have you tried using a promise?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

@MikeB the browser should only unload the current page, when it has received something to replace it with - but if that request triggers the download dialog as intended, that would not be the case. I'm guessing this is probably rather a UI issue - unless specific conditions such as the browser being set to accept downloads and automatically save them without further user interaction weren't mentioned here, I am not sure if two seconds is enough time for the user to confirm the download dialog ... and maye that blocks the "next one" from appearing ...?

im use this code to fix js. download multiple file with new tabs
function downloadFilesInNewTabs(fileArray) {
    top.sapphire.alert('Starting file downloads in new tabs', true);
    fileArray.forEach((file, index) => {
        const url = "WEB-CUSTOM/Download/DownloadFile_00.jsp?filepath=WEB-CUSTOM/ControlChart/Output/" + file;
        const newTab = window.open(url, '_blank');

        if (!newTab) {
            console.error(`Failed to open new tab for file: ${file}`);
            top.sapphire.alert(`Failed to open new tab for file: ${file}`, true);
        }
    });
}

